# Detect word at the end of the sentence with regex

Tags: regex, linux, nginx, lua

I start in regex. My string can look like `nxs_flo.nexus` or`127.0.0.1` or `nxs_flo.nexus.com`

I want to filter only strings of `nxs_flo.nexus` type. So I want to test if in my string there is `.nexus` AND that it is at the end of my string.

Here is what i did to filter a `.` but i do not see how to do it for filter `.nexus` and that it is at the end:

```
if ngx.var.host:match("(.-)%.") == nil then
```

Or this for detect `.nexus` but it does not work :

```
if ngx.var.host:match("(.*).nexus") == nil then
```

Comment: try escaping the . in the second example, also append a $ at the end to only match end of line

Comment: @AlexanderDaum : like this : `ngx.var.host:match("(.*).nexus$") == nil`

Comment: I don't know about lua or nginx regex implementations, but you might have to write %. instead of . to match the charactor . instead of any character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
local host = [[nxs_flo.nexus]]
if host:match("%.nexus$") == nil then
    print("No '.nexus' at the end of the string!")  
else
    print("There is '.nexus' at the end of the string!")    
end
-- => There is '.nexus' at the end of the string!
```

See the [online Lua demo](https://ideone.com/qJd8nW).

The pattern matches:

- `%.` - a literal `.` char
- `nexus` - the `nexus` substring
- `$` - end of string.